# Removing directory using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, directory

I'm new to codeigniter so please forgive me,  I am trying to make codeigniter delete a base folder (I don't know what the right term is, it's the folder where I put my uploaded files and its located in the root of my codeigniter project). Since I am new to codeigniter, I don't have any idea on how to make use of the File Helper reference in the codeigniter api. I hope someone can help me with this.

Furthermore, the delete function I am trying to make needs to delete also all of its contents, so empty or not, the folder gets deleted. I'm guessing, it would use a recursive type of deletion...I'm not so sure at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can delete all files using [delete_files](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/file_helper.html) function

```
$path=$this->config->base_url().'dir_name';
$this->load->helper("file"); // load the helper
delete_files($path, true); // delete all files/folders
```

Above code will delete all files and folders from the given path and if once the directory is empty then you can use [rmdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) which deletes an empty directory, like

```
rmdir($path);
```

The folder should permit relevant permissions, which means files/folder must be writable or owned by the system in order to be deleted.

Comment: thanks for answering but im having trouble on how to apply this, should i put this in the controller? or model?

Comment: Yes, put it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using "delete_files" function:

```
$path = "the path that has files those will be deleted";
$this->load->helper("file"); // load codeigniter file helper
delete_files($path, true , false, 1); //  second and the last parameters are required, second parameter should be true and the last parameter should be greater than 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Delete Directory
public function delete_directory($folderName)
{
      $this->load->helper('file'); // Load codeigniter file helper

      $dir_path  = 'uploads/'.$folderName;  // For check folder exists
      $del_path  = './uploads/'.$folderName.'/'; // For Delete folder

      if(is_dir($dir_path))
      {
           delete_files($del_path, true); // Delete files into the folder
           rmdir($del_path); // Delete the folder

           return true;
      }
      return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->helper("file"); // load codeigniter file helper
delete_files('./path/to/directory/', TRUE); // Delete all files/folders in the dir
```

If you want to delete the empty folder(dir), add below line after above two lines

```
rmdir('./path/to/directory');
```