# How to delete uploaded files with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I used the Codeigniter's Upload Class to upload images to a folder in the project. In the database I only store the the url generated after upload the image, so when I want to delete a row in the db I also need to delete the image. How can I do it in codeigniter?

I will be grateful for your answers.

Comment: `delete_row_from_db(); unlink('/path/to/file');`?

Comment: It shows me an error, something like I can't delete it from a "http://..."

Comment: you can't delete from a url, you can only unlink a local filesystem path.

Comment: If the file is on the server, /path/to/file should not have the http:// protocol. You need to specify the actual path in the filesystem of the server.

Comment: You can delete all files using "delete_files" function in file helper.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178731/removing-directory-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can delete all the files in a given path, for example in the `uploads` folder, using this `deleteFiles()` function which could be in one of your models:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';

function deleteFiles($path){
    $files = glob($path.'*'); // get all file names
    foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
      if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file
        //echo $file.'file deleted';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
delete_row_from_db(); unlink('/path/to/file');
```

/path/to/file must be real path.

For eg :

if your folder is like this htp://example.com/uploads

$path = **realpath**(APPPATH . '../uploads');

**APPPATH = path to the application folder.**

Its working...

Answer (score 1):

if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') 
             {

```
            $config['upload_path']   = './upload/image'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
            $config['file_name']    = base64_encode("" . mt_rand());
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $this->upload->initialize($config); 

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) 
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'We had an error trying. Unable upload  image');
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                @unlink("./upload/image/".$_POST['prev_image']);
                $testData['image'] = $image_data['file_name'];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$m_img_real= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/shop/real_images/'.$data['settings']->shop_now;
$m_img_thumbs = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/shop/thumbs/'.$data['settings']->shop_now;

if (file_exists($m_img_real) && file_exists($m_img_thumbs)) 
{
     unlink($m_img_real);
     unlink($m_img_thumbs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<input type="file" name="new_file" data-required="1" class="" />
<input type="hidden" name="old_file" value="echo your old file name"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
```

Controller:

```
function edit_image() {

 if(isset($_FILES['new_file']['name']) && $_FILES['new_file']['name'] != '') {

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_file']['tmp_name'],'./public_html/banner/'.$_FILES['new_file']['name']);

                $upload = $_FILES['new_file']['name'];

                $name = $post['old_file'];
                @unlink("./public_html/banner/".$name);
            }
            else {

                $upload = $post['old_file'];
            }              

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `delete_files('path')` function offered by CI framework itself:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_data = $this->upload->data();
unlink($image_data['full_path']);
```

This line `$this->upload->data()` will return many information about uploaded file. You can print information and work accordingly.